# MongoDB and Django model structure

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models

I have recently started using Django and so far I have only tried using SQLite for the database. Now, I want to use MongoDB, but I have run into a small problem when defining my models.

I was working with NodeJS and Mongoose before, and I had already defined the model:

```
date : Date,
type : String,
   exerc : {
      name : String,
      series : {
         weight : Number,
         rep : Number,
         quant : Number
      }
   }
```

In Django I am still a bit lost. I thought about two different approaches, but I am not sure if neither is correct.

The first approach would be this (ignoring the data types, for now):

```
class Work(models.Model):
  date
  type
  exerc #reference to Exerc

class Exerc(models.Model):
  name
  series #reference to Serie

class Serie(models.Model):
  weight
  rep
  quant
```

The second approach would basically involve adding the type ListField() to exerc and embed the serie also as a ListField() on the Work model. As I am not sure how this works (I have only seen a couple of examples), I would like to know if this would work for me.

Also, I would need to link the Work with a specific User (another model to be created). What is the best way to do that?

Can anyone clear this up for me?

Answer (score 0):

As concerns the best approach to models design, it depends on your use case. If you need some filters on "Exerc" and "Serie", if you need frequently update/add/delete "Exerc" and "Serie" instances - first approach would be better. If you always get all "Exerc" and "Serie" for particular "Work" instance and not update your records so often - second approach suitable too.

As for relation between "Work" and "User" - it depends on app that you are using to interact with mongodb.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try the first approach then. I wasn't sure if ForeignKey was possible in a non-relational database.

Comment: Sorry, I did't consider that you use non-relational database. As I know django doesn't support mongodb by default, so possible decision depends on app that you are using for interact with mongodb.

Comment: Do you think that it would be probably better to use SQLite?

Comment: Depends on your project's load. If it small project it would be easier to work with SQLite. But MongoDB is very perspective database engine.

Comment: It is a small project. Regardless, I feel that working with a non-relational database is more suitable on this case. Could you give me a hand on how I could get this working using Django and MongoDB?

Comment: Sure, http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ . This is a good backend for django to work with mongodb.